# Как вставлять строки в verticalHeaderItem()?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, qtablewidget

Как вставлять строки в `verticalHeaderItem()`?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.alphabet = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхчцьыъэюя"

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))  # Устанавливаем размеры
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget")  # Устанавливаем заголовок окна
        central_widget = QWidget(self)  # Создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)  # Устанавливаем центральный виджет

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()  # Создаём QGridLayout
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)  # Устанавливаем данное размещение в центральный виджет

        table = QTableWidget(self)  # Создать таблицу
        table.setColumnCount(len(self.alphabet))
        table.setRowCount(len(self.alphabet))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list(self.alphabet))
        alphabet = self.alphabet
        for i in range(len(self.alphabet)):
            table.verticalHeaderItem(1)
            for j in range(len(self.alphabet)):
                table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(alphabet[j]))
            alphabet = alphabet[-1] + alphabet[:-1]

        # делаем ресайз колонок по содержимому
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()



        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)  # Добавляем таблицу в сетку


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Покажите код, который у вас уже написан.

Comment: @S. Nick обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QTableWidget::**setVerticalHeaderLabels**(const QStringList &labels)
>
> Устанавливает метки вертикального заголовка с помощью меток.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, \
    QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.alphabet = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхчцьыъэюя"

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))    # Устанавливаем размеры
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget")    # Устанавливаем заголовок окна
        central_widget = QWidget(self)         # Создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)  # Устанавливаем центральный виджет

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()            # Создаём QGridLayout
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)  # Устанавливаем данное размещение в центральный виджет

        table = QTableWidget(self)             # Создать таблицу
        table.setColumnCount(len(self.alphabet))
        table.setRowCount(len(self.alphabet))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list(self.alphabet))
        
        alphabet = self.alphabet
        for i in range(len(self.alphabet)):
            table.verticalHeaderItem(1)
            for j in range(len(self.alphabet)):
                table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(alphabet[j]))
            alphabet = alphabet[-1] + alphabet[:-1]

        # делаем ресайз колонок по содержимому
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(list(self.alphabet))                   # +++

        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)  # Добавляем таблицу в сетку


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]